# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, mbstring

When i run

```
php -v
```

Got an error like

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/php_mbstring.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/php_mbstring.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

And tried the solution with install mbstring like

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

after that tried with enable it like:

```
sudo phpdismod mbstring # disable mbstring extension
sudo phpenmod mbstring # enable mbstring extension again
```

But enable to find the solution also tried with `php.ini`.

Comment: How many installation of php are there on your system check in `/etc/`

Comment: There is two folder php5 and php. in php there is 3 different folder 5.6,7.0,7.1 @MASIDDIQUI

Comment: Thats creating the problem ... In one environment its better to install one php, so you may think of removing 5.6, 7.0

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI but when i run `phpnfo()` at that time it shows 5.6 and when run `php -v` then it shows 7.1.x

Comment: To install mbstring in php5.6 you need to do is `sudo apt-get install php5-mbstring` and  then try

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI already tried that but didn't seems working.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you have multiple versions of PHP installed. It also is likely that all those versions of PHP refer to the very same configuration file (`php.ini`). This configuration file then loads extensions which are available just for some of the PHP installations but not for all.

Furthermore, it seems as if you use a different version of PHP from command line than for your web server.

- If you run `php -i` from command line, you get information about default PHP CLI (command line interface) installation.
- If you add a file `phpinfo.php` with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` somewhere in your `htdocs` (web server) directory, you see the default PHP version for the web.

Even more strange is that you are trying to load a Windows extension `php_mbstring.dll` even though you seem to be on Linux.

You should check for each installed PHP which configuration file it uses. The information is part of the output of `php -i` or `phpinfo()`. Make sure different versions of PHP use different configuration files.

Check where the DLL file is loaded from via `grep -iRn 'php_mbstring.dll' /etc`. Remove this line or change it to the Linux extension (likely `extension=mbstring.so`).

Comment: My issue was the same but with `php_openssl.dll`
I used `php -i` to see where my configuration `php.ini` was located.
In there found that the line `extension=php_openssl.dll` was uncommented. `.dll` files are for Windows environments so won't be found on Linux